# Excelc calculate a value based on dropdown list selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Novice excel user here. I am working with Excel 2013

I have 11 cells in a row with dropdown lists.  The drop down lists have 6 texts values:
Choose One
Exceptional
Excellent
Successfull
Needs Improvement
Unsuccessful

Depending one which is chosen they need to have values of 5 (exceptional) to 1 (Unsuccessful) and 0 being (Choose One).  Some cells may only have Choose One (being not selected).  I need to add the add up the total values of what is selected.  So if 5 were "Selected", 4 were "Excellent" and 2 were Choose One, the total would be 31.  I need to calculate the value of 31 / the number selected which in this case is 9 to equal 3.44. How do I create a formula in a cell to take all of that into consideration?

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your dropdowns from A to K (11 cells), 
and the values you indicated, you could use the formula

```
 =COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Exceptional")*5 +  COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Excellent")*4  + COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Successful")*3  + COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Needs Improvement")*2 +  COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Unsuccessful")*1 + COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Choose One")*0 +  COUNTIF(A2:K2,"")*0
```

to get the totals

you could use the fourmula

```
 =COUNTA(A2:K2)
```

to give you the number of cells that have some data

then you could simply have the combined formula

```
=(COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Exceptional")*5 +  COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Excellent")*4  + COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Successful")*3  + COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Needs Improvement")*2 +  COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Unsuccessful")*1 + COUNTIF(A2:K2,"Choose One")*0 +  COUNTIF(A2:K2,"")*0)/COUNTA(A2:K2)
```

to you give you the number you want

Comment: The first part works well.  There will always be data in the cell.  If not selected or modified, it will be "Choose One" which is 0.  How do I count all cells that are not "Choose One"?

Comment: =(COUNTIF(P4:Z4,Sheet2!A3)*5 + COUNTIF(P4:Z4,Sheet2!A4)*4 + COUNTIF(P4:Z4,Sheet2!A5)*3 + COUNTIF(P4:Z4,Sheet2!A6)*2 ++ COUNTIF(P4:Z4,Sheet2!A7)*1)/COUNTIF(P4:Z4,"<>Select One")